# Portrait Movie Poster Aspect Size

Tags: css, video, video-streaming, aspect

I am getting really stuck working out the aspect ratio of portrait movie posters.

For landscape, it is simple nearly every movie website uses 16/9.

So for a 200px wide movie poster, the height would be.

```
200/16*9 = 112.5
```

I read somewhere that you just reverse the landscape aspect. for example a 200px wide movie poster the height would be.

```
200/9*16 = 355
```

This doesn't look right the posters look far too high and if you look at a google portrait movie poster it is not 16/9 reversed.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/w7lXl6raeh4/movieposter.webp

I need to be able to generate the aspect ratio for portrait rather than hardcode the image size as I need them to be dynamic on different browse widths.

Here is an example? https://output.jsbin.com/nexahagose/

Any suggestions would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Portrait would be

```
width: 200px;
height: calc(200px * (16/9));
```

Landscape

```
width: 200px;
height: calc(200px / (16/9));
```

I don't think the image you linked to has this aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the response I know how to work it out with css the question I am asking is what is the correct aspect ratio for portrait movie posters 16/9 reversed looks wrong it's far too tall how are the people doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the posters to have the ratio 16:9:

```
height: 200px;
width: calc(200px * (9/16));
object-fit: cover; // this will maintain the correct ratio instead of scaling the image
```

You can also check the size of the posters (and the ratio) with javascript and do something with that later:

```
let img = document.getElementById('poster'); // or whatever you name it
let width = img.clientWidth;
let height = img.clientHeight;
let ratio = height / width;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I know how to work it out with css the question I am asking is what is the correct aspect ratio for portrait movie posters 16/9 reversed looks wrong it's far too tall how are the people doing it.

Comment: In your code example you have two elements with aspect ratio 16:9 on top of each other, which is why it looks tall. It’s just the position issue. And as I said, you can find the correct aspect ratio with JS.